# Nhibernate Nunit - clear database between testcases

Tags: performance, nhibernate, nunit

We have a rather extensive test suite that takes forever to execute.
After each test has completed, the database (MSSQL) needs to be emptied so it is fresh for the next testcase.
The way we do this is by temporarily removing all foreign keys, TRUNCATE'ing all tables, and re-adding the FKs.

This step takes somewhere between 2-3 seconds, according to NHProfiler. All the time is seemingly spent with the FK operations.

Our current method is clearly not optimal, but which way should we go to improve the performance ? The number of elements which are actually deleted from the DB is completely insignificant compared to the number of operations for the FK removal/additions.

Using an in-memory SQLite database is not an option, as the code under test uses MSSQL specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap everything in a transaction and in the end just rollback everything. That's how I do it. It allows also to run tests in parallel.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't an option here. Some of the components under test, have testcases that ensure they persist their computed results

Comment: You can use a distributed transaction wrapping everything

Answer (score 0):

what about using SQL Server Compact, create the database from the mapping files using nhibernate schema create and load the data for each test. if you are talking about a trivial amount data.

Have a look at this blog post - [Using SQL Server Compact Edition for Unit testing](http://www.differentpla.net/content/2009/03/using-sql-server-compact-edition-unit-testing)

Alternativly you could use Fluent Migrator to create the database schema and load the data for each test.

Comment: Good idea about MsSqlCe. Unfortunately, it doesn't support nvarchar(max), which some of the mapping files contain.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using a DB in your tests? Surely you should be mocking the persistence mechanism?  Unless you're actually trying to test that part of the functionality you're wasting time and resources actually inserting/updating/deleting data.

The fact that your tests rely on ms sql specifics and returned data hints at the possibility that your architecture needs looking at.

I'm not meaning to sound rude here - I'm just surprised no one else has picked you up on this.

w://

Comment: when working with an ORM, i find it extremely valuable to test database interaction to make sure my selects work. I've had some extremely long DetachedCriteria statements that I wanted to make sure pulled from the database what I expect it to.

Comment: As for MSSQL specifics, if you know that you'll never change the underlying database, why not take advantage of their differences.  I've used computed columns because it makes life simpler even though it's not supported on databases such as sqlite. I work in an environment that has standardized on MS and has invested tons of money and I can say with the greatest of confidence, we won't be using Oracle or any other database for our internal apps.

Comment: And all of your tests are integration tests like this or just some?

Comment: The fact that there could be "extremely long DetachedCriteria" makes me a bit edgy. I'm also not sure you should be testing nHIbernate like this - you should be testing your code. Alarm bells are ringing is all i'm saying.

Comment: In the optimal world, the tests would be split out into more test suites. But in reality, that will not happen. Most of the tests that take a long time are related to the data layer, so it would not make sense to mock it.  The reason for MsSql specifics is simply that we've added functions to the NH-Dialect, and see no reason to implement somethat that may or may not behave in the same way for databases that will never be used. We may, however, end up having to attempt some workarounds and use Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I've done in the past to help speed up database integration tests. First thing I did was I ended up having a sql script that actually creates the entire database from scratch. This can be easily accomplished using a tool like Red-Gate SQL Compare against a blank database.

Second I created a script that removed all of the database objects from an existing database.

Then I needed a script that populated the database with test data. Again, simple to create using Red-Gate tools. You don't need/want a ton of data here, just enough to cover your test cases.

With those items in place, I created one test class with all of my read-only operations in there. In the init of that class, i cleared a local sql server express instance, ran the create script and then ran the populate script. This ensured the database was initialized correctly for all of the read-only tests.

For tests that actually manipulate the database, we just did the same routing as above except that we did it on test init as opposed to class init.

Obviously the more database manipulation tests you have, the longer it will take to run all of your tests. If it becomes unruly, you should look at categorizing your tests and only running what is necessary locally and running the full suite on a continuous integration server.